# Why can't I install an app (says "could not be found")?

Tags: iphone, itunes, install

I just got an iPhone SE. I did a backup from my 4, then told iTunes to restore the new phone from the backup.

It said there were a bunch of apps it couldn't install because they cannot be found.

As just one example, Access RPN is on my 4, shows in my iTunes under "My Apps", but without art. When I go to the iTunes Store link, it says "Downloaded" so I can't redownload it.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
I found an Apple page that says to do this I need an iTunes backup, AND a phone that's not set up. So I erased my SE and tried again. This got many more of the apps installed and their data recovered, but some still aren't working. Access RPN, my example app, still does not work.

Comment: Are all those apps still available in the App Store?  When a developer removes their app from the store you'll get a similar situation.

Comment: Access RPN at the very least is: https://itunes.apple.com/gm/app/access-rpn-calculator/id317845869?mt=8

Comment: Are you sines in to the same country 's App Store and with the same ID you used when you got those apps?  Also, if these are older apps without recent updates, like Access RPN, maybe they can't run on the latest iOS version.   That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: I checked with the author of RPN, he says it works on his 9.3 device. My App Store has a section called "Made in Canada" in it, so I'm pretty sure I'm still in the right App Store.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas on this one.  Those are the only things that I know will cause the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in iTunes on the computer, it says "Downloaded". But on the device itself, go to

App Store -> Updates -> Purchased -> My Purchases

and select the "Not on this iPhone" tab. That shows all apps that didn't get transferred. Click the cloud icon to download them.

This even preserved the apps' data, because I had done a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, the root cause* was different, and I got it fixed. The `myapp.ipa` file was missing and **I recovered it from a mac backup (from TimeMachine)**.

I will try to be as detailed as I can remember:

1. find the app's location on mac > `iTunes`: right-lick on it to `Get Info` > `File` > `location`, to find where the `myapp.ipa` was supposed to be at
2. if it's not on this location on `Finder`, then open `Time Machine` (maybe you need to plug in your external HD 1st) and try to find the file on an older backup
3. copy the file to your desktop, then drag & drop to `iTunes` apps library. A message _ _ _[*pls edit here if you know its text*] will ask you if you want to replace the app. Choose "Yes" (at your own risk).
4. on iTunes, with your iPhone plugged in, select this app to be installed on your phone as you normally would do. Done!

---

*possible root causes related to this fix:

1. app is not maintained by the developer anymore (e.g. [warning-this-app-will-not-work-with-future-versions-of-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346586/warning-this-app-will-not-work-with-future-versions-of-ios))
2. app available on the App Store of a different country

Answer (score -4):

You just open the Xcode devices, and select the device and add whatever the app you need to install.. Thats all

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions